# Sharing database connection

Tags: android, sqlite, locking, thread-safety

I just need some validation that this is a workable way to share a `SQLlite` database connection across my `Activities` and `Services` of my app, by using a helper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper
{
    private static DBItems dbItems;
    private static SQLiteDatabase sdbItemsRead, sbItemsWrite;

    public static synchronized DBItems getHelper(Context context)
    {
        if (dbItems == null)
            dbItems = new DBItems(context);

        return dbItems;
    }

    public static synchronized SQLiteDatabase select(Context context)
    {
        if (sdbItemsRead == null)
            sdbItemsRead = getHelper(context).getReadableDatabase();

        return sdbItemsRead;
    }

    public static synchronized SQLiteDatabase write(Context context)
    {
        if (sbItemsWrite == null)
            sbItemsWrite = getHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();

        return sbItemsWrite;
    }
}
```

In my code I'm calling this to select data:

```
DatabaseHelper.select(this).rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
```

and this to write data:

```
DatabaseHelper.write(this).update("tbl_items", cv, "[id] = ?", new String[] { itemId.toString() });
```

I need to do this because I'm calling the database from different threads (UI and background) and I was getting "database is locked" exceptions thrown.

Comment: What is your take on writing a Content Provider?

Comment: @sixfeetsix If this is an good way to share a database connection.  Just looking for some validation after doing my own research.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating database and calling in some activities then it will work fine, but if you want that your database should run along with service then it is always better to write the database in custom Content Provider.

Custom Content Provider will help you to run your database in background along with service.

you can refer the custom content provider from [this link](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/custom-content-provider-in-android/).

Comment: So are you saying my solution won't work with a `Service` or a `Custom Content Provider` is a better solution?

Comment: yes...it will be better if you use custom content provider for your database running in background...